# Linked objects are not rendering properly?

Tags: rendering, linked-data

When I render my scene there seems to be an issue with my floor panels. These are individual floor panels, so I created a separate file and linked the floor panel in my new blender file. Then I did ALT D for each one to keep my file size from getting too large. This image is before I render.

[image]
However, the rendered file has the floor panels in different places and some not showing at all? I am certain this has to do with linking the floor panels, but not sure what I am missing? Also, I still have to create the floor pedestals which supports the floor panels that also have several parts, and I would like to link it as well. (Well, if I can get this to work first)

Thank you

[image]

**Edit 1:**

Here is my Blender File. After some time working on this, it seems as though when I attempt to select a row of tiles to copy (ALT D) I begin to have the Render problems. When I only copy one floor tile at a time it seems to render fine.

I wonder if this is a bug or just how it is? Since I have so many floor tiles, I really do not want to have to individually select each floor tile and copy.

[image]

**Edit #2:**

I retract my last statement above; "select a row of tiles to copy (ALT D) I begin to have the Render problems. When I only copy one floor tile at a time it seems to render fine. "

As I added more tiles one by one my renders are still not rendering properly.

If I cannot get the linked floor tiles to render properly does anyone have any suggestions on duplicating these tiles without creating a huge file? So far I have tried having the floor tiles on a separate layer then Shift D to duplicate the each tile and rows; approximately 400 individual floor tiles. However, I am looking at a file at 700 MB which is way to much, obviously.

Thank you

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5976" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5976/)

Comment: I am still not having any luck with rendering this without the floor panels being all over the place and missing. I even created a new file and linked it with no luck. I need to create over 400 floor panels without my file getting too large. Anyone know another way to do this besides linking?

Comment: It seems to be rendering just fine for now. I decided to link the objects individually versus as a group.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help you, I've got some problems with the 2.8 version, nice if you fixed your problems